# Permutation algorithm to simulate $X$, $Y$, $Z$ uniform on $(0,1)$ with $X+Y+Z = 1$

Tags: probability, statistics, simulation

> Permutation algorithm to simulate $X$, $Y$, $Z$ uniform on $(0,1)$ with $X+Y+Z = 1$

**Edit**:

Sorry, I tend to jump back and forth between math notation and computer science notation....often to the chagrin of my more rigorous colleagues (and Math.SE folks ;-)

Also, I accidentally copied a formula, so the problem was *over*specified. The last variable is determined by the previous two.

And yes $\pi_i$ is the send element of the random permutation group $\pi$.

I hope this clears things up.

---

Is it possible to satisfy the title condition if I use the following algorithm?

Let $V:=(X,Y,Z)$ be a vector of unspecified variables.

1. Generate a random permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$, call this $\pi$
2. Let $V_{\pi_1}\sim U(0,1),V_{\pi_2}\sim U(0,1-V_{\pi_1}),V_{\pi_3}=1-V_{\pi_1}-V_{\pi_3}$
3. Go back to step 1

I'm hoping that the pdf of $V$ will have standard uniform marginal. It seems like the permutation operation ensures that the components of $V$ have standard uniform marginal over many iterations, since I am uniformly sampling over the permutations of the components.

Is there a subtle flaw to this? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: It seems like the probability that the maximum of the variables is high ends up too high.

Comment: Can you give another description of what you want to get at the end here? In what respect, exactly, are the three variables meant to be $U(0,1)$? Are you trying to find a uniform distribution on the set $\{ X+Y+Z=1 \}$?

Comment: What is the relationship between $V$ and $V_{\pi_1}$? I'm not understanding what is meant by 1.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Presumably $\pi_i$ is the $i$th member of the permutation chosen.

Comment: Knowing $X, Y, Z \sim U(0,1)$, you want to simulate $(X, Y, Z)$ conditionally on $X+Y+Z = 1$, right?

Comment: The space $x+y+z=1$ with $0<x,y,z<1$ is a triangle, so really should be parameterized by two random variables, not three.

Comment: Ah, I assumed $X,Y,Z$ were known, since $V:=(X,Y,Z)$ means "define $V$ as..." If $X,Y,Z$ are not known, then (1) is nonsensical. Basically, very sloppy notation for how $X,Y,Z$ mare meant to be defined. @Ian

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It makes sense to me from the pointer perspective ($V$ is a pointer to an array whose first entry is $X$, second entry is $Y$, third entry is $Z$). I agree it's a bit strange from the mathematical perspective.

Comment: Except $X,Y,Z$ aren't defined yet. $V$ at that point is a container for things that are going to be defined later, which is sort of a mess. I'd start with $V_1=U(0,1), V_2=U(0,1-V_1), V_3=U(0,1-V_1-V_2)$ then define $X=V_{\pi_1}, Y=V_{\pi_2}, Z=V_{\pi_3}$. That avoids the odd definitional loop

Comment: In any event, what the OP wants is impossible, as indicated by @did's answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews see my edits...there were a few notational hiccups in my first go.

Comment: @Ian see my edits...there were a few notational hiccups in my first go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditions $X+Y+Z=1$ and $X$, $Y$, $Z$ uniform on $(0,1)$, are incompatible since the first one implies $E(X)+E(Y)+E(Z)=1$ and the second one implies $E(X)=E(Y)=E(Z)=\frac12$.

Comment: +1...you are correct. My first go had some mixed up notation and one too many copy and pastes in LaTeX. Hope the edits clarify things.

Comment: You lost me: which changes in your question are relevant to my answer? (Not to mention that to modify a question *after* an answer is posted is dubious.)

Comment: First, its not modify as much as correct. My fist formulation simply had errors. I changed it so that the random third component of $V$ is determined by the first two randomly chosen components.

Comment: Although, I realize that this is irrelevant, since expectations are independent of the correlation structure. I guess I'd end up getting three, identical, skewed distributions with expected value 1/3.

Comment: Indeed, and the density $g$ of this distribution is $$g(x)=\left(\tfrac13-\tfrac23\log x\right)\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}(x).$$

Comment: Isn't $log(0)=-\infty$

Comment: Yes, and? Densities have values in $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: Nothing, just wanted to be sure, not used to seeing infinite densities a lot, so it raised a yellow flag.